# Is there a reliable way to determine the number of times an index is being used per stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently trying to write some queries for finding out how many times an index is being used for a particular table and what stored procedures are using those indexes. I have tried searching through the Internet and Stack Exchange websites for some helpful information and I was able to put together a helpful query for finding out how many times an index is being used, but my second query for finding out what stored procedures are using a particular index has been returning incorrect counts.

Here is my first (working) query for the number of times an index is being used:

```
DECLARE @Index SYSNAME = N'PK_SampleIdx';

SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(idx_stats.object_id) as ObjectName,
    idx_stats.index_id,
    ISNULL(idx.name, 'Table') as IndexName,
    SUM(ptn_stats.used_page_count) * 8 as IndexSizeKB,
    idx_stats.user_seeks,
    idx_stats.user_scans,
    idx_stats.user_lookups,
    idx_stats.user_updates  
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats idx_stats
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes idx ON 
    (
        idx.object_id = idx_stats.object_id AND idx.index_id = idx_stats.index_id
    ) 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats ptn_stats ON 
    (
        ptn_stats.object_id = idx.object_id AND ptn_stats.index_id = idx.index_id
    )
WHERE idx_stats.database_id = DB_ID (N'SampleDb') AND
      OBJECT_NAME(idx_stats.object_id) = N'SampleTbl'
GROUP BY idx_stats.object_id, 
         idx_stats.index_id, 
         idx.name, 
         idx_stats.user_seeks,
         idx_stats.user_scans,
         idx_stats.user_lookups,
         idx_stats.user_updates

---SAMPLE RESULT---
ObjectName  index_id IndexName     IndexSizeKB user_seeks user_scans user_lookups user_updates
SampleTbl   0        Table         3657416     0          8          0            2
SampleTbl   2        PK_SampleIdx  3580432     1411       0          0            2
Sampletbl   6        IDX_SampleIdx 1616544     0          0          0            2
```

Here is my second (not working as intended) query for the list of stored procedures that are being used for a specific index:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.objectid)) as StoredProcedure,
       s.execution_count, 
       CONVERT(XML, p.query_plan) as XMLQueryPlan 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan
    (
        s.plan_handle, s.statement_start_offset, s.statement_end_offset
    ) AS p
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE p.query_plan LIKE '%Index="\[' + @Index + '\]"%' ESCAPE '\'

---SAMPLE RESULT---
StoredProcedure execution_count XMLQueryPlan
[_SampleSP]     7               <ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com..."
[_SampleSP2]    2               <ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com..."
[_SampleSP3]    1               <ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com..."
NULL            2               <ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com..."
NULL            1               <ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com..."
```

The first query shows that the `PK_SampleIdx` index was used a total of 1413 times (1411 for the seeks on SELECT statements and 2 for the updates on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements). But, the second query counted that it was only used 13 times. I'm also not sure why there are NULL values for the stored procedure column but that is not part of my question.

I do understand that `user_seeks` returns the number of times that index was used as an Index Seek while `execution_count` returns the number of times that particular query plan was executed. Because of this I have tried replacing the `s.execution_count` column in the second query with this to count the number of times that index appeared in the query plan:

```
((LEN(p.query_plan) - LEN(REPLACE(p.query_plan,@Index,''))) / LEN(@Index)) AS 'execution_count',
```

However, this change still under-counted the number of times the index was being used.

I have looked at [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248375/2843157)'s answer from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247713/how-to-find-what-stored-procedures-are-using-what-indexes) and modified it to only look for the particular index but instead of under counting the result like my second query did, it over counted by 100+. Here is the modified query that I was using:

```
with xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' as sp)
select q.execution_count
     , x.value(N'@Database', N'sysname') as [Database]
     , x.value(N'@Table', N'sysname') as [Table]
     , x.value(N'@Index', N'sysname') as [Index]
     , substring(t.text, q.statement_start_offset/2,   
       case when 0 < q.statement_end_offset then (q.statement_end_offset - q.statement_start_offset)/2
       else len(t.text) - q.statement_start_offset/2 end) as [Statement]
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats q
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) as t
    cross apply query_plan.nodes(N'//sp:IndexScan/sp:Object') s(x)
WHERE x.value(N'@Table', N'sysname') = '[SampleTbl]' AND
      x.value(N'@Index', N'sysname') = '[PK_SampleIdx]'
order by total_logical_reads desc
```

My question is this:

Is there a reliable way to determine the number of times an index is being used per stored procedure? If so then how do I get this information?

Comment: Well technically speaking a stored procedure doesn't use an index. An index is a way for a query to more quickly find rows and those queries are part of the execution generated for a procedure. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @SeanLange You are right that stored procedure doesn't technically use an index. What I'm trying to say is I want the count for the # of times an index appears in the query plans per stored procedures to match my 1st query that was only counting the # of times the index was used at all. Or as close to the counts as possible since I understand it would be hard to count the ones that were used but not from a stored procedure. This information would help me with eliminating indexes based on what stored procedures are being used and the number of times the index was being used.

Comment: Does it really matter how many times it might be accessed from a stored procedure? If it is used in the procedure that would likely be sufficient to demonstrate it shouldn't be eliminated. Maybe it would be more beneficial to examine unused indexes first? If an index is being used it is probably important enough to keep it around. Unless you have identified a particular procedure as being a performance issue I think you may put far more effort into this than you can hope to benefit.

Comment: @SeanLange It's really just me being picky with wanting the counts to match, and I wanted to make sure to list all of the stored procedures that shows in their query plan that the specific index is used. The reason I am wanting to eliminate an index is because my actual table is huge along with 5 other indexes being almost the same size as the table and this causes my INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements to be very slow (I asked a question about the table's indexing in this [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87691/uniquifier-on-non-unique-clustered-index-vs-unique-clustered-index)).

Comment: Also, this index in question is overlapping another index but the other index is used more often. The overlapping index is also 3 times bigger the overlapped index. So I was hoping that removing the overlapping index would speed up my INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements while minimizing any slowdown on the SELECT statements.

Comment: Eliminating indexes based upon usage is probably a bad idea.  You could have a poorly formed query that is causing an index scan on the PK and ignoring your index lets say on a date field because the date field isn't clustered.  Is it the fault of the index or the fault of the schema.  I would use what you have written to analyze why some indexes aren't being used while others are.

Comment: @ewahner The reason why I'm eliminating indexes based on usage is because the index could be used for something that was not really needed (in my instance it was only being used to add entries to a log table that is not being used for anything else) and it's just slowing down the IUD statements. I'm having to work on a database that was badly designed and I'm not allowed to change the design. I can only remove indexes if they are not very beneficial or optimize any stored procedures that are slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query optimizer will calculate which indexes to use based on many factors.  Two executions of the same stored procedure may end up using different indexes.  The process of counting the number of times a particular index is used by a particular stored procedure is likely not a useful exercise.

A better approach would be to analyze the individual queries that a stored procedure is using.  Look at the expected data and statistics for the tables/views referenced by the query.  If query performance is inadequate, create an index using gathered data to alleviate the offending query.